# Tomcat error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp, jdbc-pool

I have a terrible problem with Tomcat, well terrible because of this problem I've thrown away the project for more than a month now... Yet I'll still need to solve it and to go on with the project...

So it's throwing me this error:

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2
java.lang.NullPointerException

The thing is that the same application is working in the desktop version perfectlz, however when it comes to the version which is supposed to be running on the server (Tomcat 7.0.22.0 inside NetBeans 7.1.2) it just throws the Error. It seems it doesn't load the pooling driver or I don't even know...

Well here's the part responsible for that:

```
public DatabaseConnection(Parameters params) {                

    // parameters and the output                
    this.gui = params.getGui();

    // activate database pool
    connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);
    connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(params.getDbAdr(), params.getDbUser(), params.getDbPass());
    poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, connectionPool, null, null, false, true);
    driver = new PoolingDriver();
    driver.registerPool("GenTreeDatabase", connectionPool);
    //driver.registerPool("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:GenTreeDatabase", connectionPool);        

}

public void openConn() {
    if (allowOutput) gui.print("Getting connection to database");
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:GenTreeDatabase");
        if (con != null) {
            if (allowOutput) gui.print("Connection to database was successful");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        gui.err(specificError + "Error getting connection to database - " + ex);
    }
}
```

It happens at the point where it tries to get the connection, then it gets a null pointer exception, since the connection is not retrieved successfuly.

I'm not familiar with Tomcat and up until this moment, Netbeans handled tomcat fine...
The thing is I hate errors like this... If you don't solve it in three days, you get so frustrated and don't wanna get back to that, you feel like hitting a wall... 
Now I tried googling a lot about it, but still it wasn't much of a help...
So I'd be really glad if somebody could help me with this. Thanks. :)

Comment: Where is the database driver (e.g. sqljdbc4.jar) located in your Tomcat directory?

Comment: @MartinWilson It's in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\lib

Comment: @home How do I get a stracktrace?

Answer (score 7):

You have to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Comment: Hi, where do I find the Catalina_home/lib? That's also a problem, I've come across this folder by googling, however my Tomcat doesn't seem to have the folder? Where do I find it?

Comment: Well right now it is in:
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.22\lib

Apache is using this folder of tomcat and the sqlijdbc4.jar is there.

Comment: what happens if your replace the database address by: jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2

Comment: well, pretty much the same :/ -
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://isd.ktu.lt:1433;DatabaseName=LN2012_bakDB2

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace. You can find it in the console of your NetBeans, or the console of your server or the log files of your server.

Comment: What is the version of your jdk? 5 or 6?
sqljdbc.jar class library requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) of version 5.0. Using sqljdbc.jar on JRE 6.0 will throw an exception when connecting to a database.
sqljdbc4.jar class library requires a Java Runtime Environment (JRE) of version 6.0. Using sqljdbc4.jar on JRE 1.4 or 5.0 will throw an exception.
See [System Requirements for the JDBC Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late to answer this question but in order to help with similar issues, Here's how I got around it.

**Quick Solution:**

Copy the `JDBC-driver JAR file` (*mine was `ojdbc6`*) into `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` (*for me it was `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext`*).

**Details:**

According to [Apache Tomcat 7 documentations](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) When Tomcat is started, it creates a set of **class-loaders** that are organized into the following parent-child relationships:

```
     Bootstrap
         |
      System
         |
      Common
      /     \
 Webapp1    Webapp2 ...
```

Each class loader, **searches for JAR files** inside a **certain directory**.  The classes and resources that they make visible are explained below:

**Bootstrap** : This class loader contains the basic runtime classes provided by the JVM, plus any classes from JAR files present in the System Extensions directory **`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`**.

**System** : This class loader is normally initialized from the contents of the **`CLASSPATH`** environment variable. All such classes are visible to both Tomcat internal classes, and to web applications. However, There are some exceptions for Tomcat.

**Common** : This class loader contains additional classes that are made visible to both Tomcat internal classes and to all web applications. This class loader looks (by default) in **`$CATALINA_BASE/lib`** and **`$CATALINA_Home/lib`** for jar files.

**Webapps** : A class loader is created for each web application that is deployed in a single Tomcat instance. All unpacked classes and resources in the **`/WEB-INF/classes`** directory of your web application, plus classes and resources in JAR files under the **`/WEB-INF/lib`** directory of your web application, are made visible to this web application, but not to other ones.

- In conclusion, buy putting the `ojdbc` JAR file inside `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` the JDBC driver, will get visible at the Bootstrap level.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered the same issue. It is because your tomcat server does not have the `jar` file of your `JDBC`. I fixed the problem by copying the `JAR` file to `lib` folder in tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

it helped me copying the mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar file to the C: \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_291 \ jre \ lib \ ext folder

Comment: When attempting to answer an old question (this is 9+ years old question), please read the existing answers before posting your own. Your answer has been mentioned / included multiple times in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393121/6670491), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669988/6670491) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63753123/6670491)